# How can I disable hole to polygon clearance in Altium?

Tags: altium, clearance, design-rules

I have a polygon reaching to the outside of the board. There I want to place mousebites for the panel, but when they are placed, there is a clearance generated around the holes that I don't want:

[image: Hole Clearance]

Where do I need to set up a custom rule in the design rules?

I tried this, but without luck:

[image: Design Rules]

Update:

[image: PadProperties]

Comment: You’ve set a rule for polygon to pad clearance but your question is about polygon to hole clearance. That’s another constraint.

Comment: Yes, because in Altium there is no "hole" just by itself. You generate one as a "pad" but without any copper. I updated the post with a picture.

Comment: What is the rule's precedence?

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you mean the priority? I set this to highest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work with the following rule setup:

[image]

The first condition 'InPoly' is, I think, the correct way to match polygons in the design rules. I'm not an expert in Altium's query language, but I was able to get the 'InPoly' condition to work and not the 'ObjectKind=' from your screenshots. I believe it may be because the ObjectKind queries return the objects and not the child primitives.

Likewise, the second condition required the condition 'HasFootprint' and then the name of my mousebite footprint. In  my library, they're called 'MOUSE BITES', but that would need to be updated to match whatever your footprint name is. It's also likely that the singular query string "Name='Free-Mousebites'" or "Designator='Mousebite'" would result in a successful match for the second condition.

Comment: Great! Thank you. 
And as I had other holes in the layout, I changed the Query to match with pads with 0mm pad expansion.